# Regex for sentences but leaves out websites

Tags: regex, web

I'm looking for a sentence regex that will not break up websites as well.

My regex is: `(\(?[^\.]+[\.!\?]\)?)`.

For sample text, I'd like

`This is a paragraph of text. It is very interesting. Yet for a test website like google.com.xyz it's broken up.`

to be three sentences:

1. This is a paragraph of text.
2. It is very interesting.
3. Yet for a test website like google.com.xyz it's broken up.

However, the last sentence is broken up thrice into:

3. Yet for a test website like google.
4. com.
5. xyz it's broken up.

How can I modify my regex to make sure that websites aren't caught in this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try finding all matches to the following regex pattern:

```
(.*?\.)(?!\S)\s*
```

Sample script in Python:

```
inp = "This is a paragraph of text. It is very interesting. Yet for a test website like google.com.xyz it's broken up."
parts = re.findall(r'(.*?\.)(?!\S)\s*', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['This is a paragraph of text.',
 'It is very interesting.',
 "Yet for a test website like google.com.xyz it's broken up."]
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(.*?\.)   match AND capture all content up to and including a full stop
(?!\S)    which is followed by whitespace or end of the string
\s*       then consume any whitespace after the full stop but before the next sentence
```